# file_get_contents with URL

Tags: php, parse-platform

I am using Parse and trying to get the image from a URL and save it as a `ParseFile`

I was successfully able to save a locally uploaded image as a `ParseFile`. How can I do the same with an image URL?

```
echo $_POST['imageURL']; // url to image
// successfully saves uploaded image
// $file = ParseFile::createFromData( file_get_contents( $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] ), $_FILES['image']['name']  );

// trying to save image from URL
$file = ParseFile::createFromData( file_get_contents( $_POST['imageURL'] ), $_FILES['image']['name']  );

$file->save();
```

This is the error I got:

```
https://www.webniraj.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/WNI01_14-Logo-275x63.png
Fatal error: Call to a member function save() on a non-object in /var/www/html/quickupload/upload.php on line 96
```

Comment: There error seems to be clear: `$_POST['imageURL']` doesn't contain a correct URL.

Comment: I tried going to `https://parse.com/image/parse-logo.png`, I got an error page.

Comment: @Barmar good catch but a working url doesnt solve the issue still

Comment: Do you get the same error with a working URL?

Comment: @Barmar updated with the new error

Comment: `ParseFile::createFromData` is apparently returning `false` because it got an error. We need to know what error it's getting.

Comment: @barmar actually you're right. my original code is now working correctly. I just entered an invalid URL.

Answer (score 0):

Try this function

```
function get_url_content($URL){
          $ch = curl_init();
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
          $data = curl_exec($ch);
          curl_close($ch);
          return $data;
      }

$file =  get_url_content('http://example.com/logo.jpg');
```

Comment: The error he got was that the URL was incorrect. Why would switching to cURL fix that?

Comment: There is always many ways to do the same thing and this is one of it.

Comment: Right, that's my point. It doesn't matter whether you use `file_get_contents` or `cURL` if the URL is wrong.

Comment: I agree with you on this.

Comment: thanks. updating the question with a working url. ill give this a try

Comment: @FaizRasool i still need to create `$file` as a parse file. the answer doesn't create the parsefile.